# populating an array with a for loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to add * in an array. This is how i do it in javaScript.

```
function makeStarString(grade) {

    var starArray = [];
    var starString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < grade; i++){
            starArray[i] = "*";
            starString = starString.concat(starArray[i]);
        }
    return starString;
}
```

The javascript version works fine but I cant make it work with php.
This is as far as i got with php.

```
function makeStarString($varGrade) {

    $starArray = array ();
    $starString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($varGrade); $i++){

            $starArray($i) = $star;
            $starString = $starString.(starArray(i));
        }   

    return $starString;
}
```

I get this error "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context" because of line `$starArray($i) = $star;`

The argument I send to the function is an Integer.
So the purpose of the function is that if i send a 5 to the function it will return *****

How can i fix my php function?

Comment: `$varGrade` is string or integer at your javascript it seems integer.If it is integer remove strlen from for loop.and also where is your $star variable.replace it with "*".Finally use [] instead of ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need stars in an array, you don't need to use a loop:

```
$starArray = array_fill(0, $varGrade, '*');
```

and if you need to turn the array into a string:

```
$starString = implode('', $starArray);
```

But if you don't really ever need to use the array of stars, it would be easier to just use str_repeat:

```
str_repeat('*', $varGrade);
```

Comment: @dont-panic I didn't know about str_repeat which is exactly what i needed. $starString = str_repeat('*', $varBetyg);

Answer (score 2):

Use `$starArray[$i]` instead of `$starArray($i)` and `starArray(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

- It would generally be a great idea to use `strlen($varGrade)` in a variable, because the `foreach` loop will have to count the length every iteration. This might bring performance issues.
- Your `$star` variable is not defined, so I have no idea what you're trying to put there. Revise your own code.
- Finally, you may use the `.=` operator to add something to existing string.

  ```
  function makeStarString($varGrade) {

  $starArray = array ();
  $starString = "";
  $length = strlen($varGrade);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

          $starArray[$i] = $star;
          $starString .= $starArray[$i];
          // equivalent to $starString = $starString . $starArray[$];
      }   

  return $starString;
  }
  ```

**UPDATE**

If you send an `int` to the function, you don't need `strlen`:

```
function makeStarString($varGrade) {

    $starArray = array ();
    $starString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $varGrade; $i++){

            $starArray[$i] = $star;
            $starString .= $starArray[$i];
            // equivalent to $starString = $starString . $starArray[$];
        }   

    return $starString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
function makeStarString($varGrade) {
    $starString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $varGrade; $i++) {
            $starString .= '*';
    }   

    return $starString;
}
```

A few notes on my modifications.

1. I don't see why you need that `$starArray` array in the first place. So I skipped it.
2. I revised your indentation. Strange indentation can make very simple code seem much more complicated than it really is. :)
3. You should ask if `$i < $varGrade`, not if `$i < strlen($varGrade)`. If you ask by `strlen()`, then you get the width of the number you enter. For example, `strlen(55)` is 2, `strlen(555)` is 3, `strlen(5555)` is 4 etc. - ignoring the fact that it's a number. You just want the for-loop to give you `$varGrade` many stars so there is no need for `strlen()`.
4. As a detail, I've put used single-quotes instead of double-quotes for strings because they're lighter (PHP doesn't parse variables inside them).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
function makeStarString($varGrade) {

    $star = "*"; // star variable wasn't defined to.
    $starArray = array ();
    $starString = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $varGrade; $i++){

            $starArray[$i] = $star; // [ ] instead of ( ) 
            $starString .= ($starArray[$i]); // $a.=$b instead of $a=$a+$b, added the $ at the i and [ ] instead of ( ) 
        }   

    return $starString;
}
```